# Leetcode algorithm takes too long to compute

Tags: c

https://leetcode.com/problems/pizza-with-3n-slices/

I understand the basics of programming and recently decided to grind leetcode so I was curious to see where I stand with the hard problems. word of warning, it doesn't look pretty. The code works but it takes exponentially more time to compute the more slices you add. Is my solution salvageable or is it a dead end and I should start with a different line of thinking?

the essence of my algorithm works with this [quick diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3L87.png), keep in mind i'm using C for this.
the first loop iterates through each individual element of the array, where it calls a function to remove the 3 slices by replacing them with -1 as a type of flag. this function is recursive, removing the slices from the next element with the old copy of the array until its gone through each element. it will exit out of the second loop and start over from the next element of the first loop.
i think i could have made it all one recursive loop but i'm not sure if i can edit leetcode's parameters for the function they gave me to complete.

```
int copyArray(int * from, int * to, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        to[i] = from[i];
    return 1;
}
int findFirstElement(int *slices, int size){
for(int i = 0; i< size; i++)
    if (slices[i] != -1)
        return i;
}
int findLastElement(int *slices, int size){
for(int i = size-1; i>=0; i--)
    if (slices[i] != -1)
        return i;
        
 
}
int getMax(int *a, int b){
    return (*a>b)? *a: b;
}
 
int removeSlices(int *slices, int pos, int slicesSize, int *max, int size){  //int size is 
//the size of the pizza which will never change unlike
// slicesSize which is decremented by 3 in each level we enter
    int *tempmax;
    int l = *max;
    tempmax = &l;
    int newSlices[size];
    int k = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int *maxmax;
    int p = 0;
    maxmax = &p;
    int newSlicesSize = slicesSize;
    copyArray(slices, newSlices, size);
    int firstElement = findFirstElement(newSlices, size);
    int lastElement = findLastElement(newSlices, size);
    *max += newSlices[pos];
    if(pos == firstElement){ // represent the array as a circle 
        newSlices[lastElement] = -1;
        newSlices[pos] = -1;
        newSlices[pos+1] = -1;
    }
    else if(pos == lastElement)
    {
        newSlices[pos-1] = -1;
        newSlices[pos] = -1;
        newSlices[firstElement] = -1;
 
    }
    else {
            newSlices[pos-1] = -1;
            newSlices[pos] = -1;
            newSlices[pos+1] = -1;
    }
 //   for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
  //      printf("%d,", newSlices[i]);
 //   printf("\n");
    newSlicesSize -= 3;
    if(newSlicesSize == 0)
        return *max;
 
 
    while(k<newSlicesSize){ //the second loop 
    m = findFirstElement(newSlices, size); 
    *tempmax = *max; // yet another max var (sorry), before we enter a new level we have to keep hold of the max so we can return to it once it has finished 
    j = removeSlices(newSlices, m+k, newSlicesSize, tempmax, size);
 
     *maxmax =getMax(maxmax, j); // maxmax holds the max of all decisions/possibilites for only the individual elements of the first loop, not the final max of all elements of the first loop
    k++;
    }
    return *maxmax;
 
}
 
 
 
int maxSizeSlices(int* slices, int slicesSize){
    int *max;
    int k = 0;
    max = &k;
    int j = 0;
    int *maxmax;
    int p = 0;
    maxmax = &p;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < slicesSize){
            *max =0;
            j = removeSlices(slices,i, slicesSize, max,slicesSize);
            *maxmax =getMax(maxmax, j);
            i++;
    }
    return *maxmax;
 
}
int main()
{
   // int slices[] = {6,3,1,2,6,2,4,3,10,4,1,4,6,5,5,3,4,7,6,5,8,7,3,8,8,1,7,1,7,8}; // gave up trying to compute this after 20min
     int slices[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // computes quickly
    int size = 6;
    int max = maxSizeSlices(slices, size);
    printf("final max: %d",max);
    return 0;
}'''
```

Comment: "Takes too long to compute". For these hard problems, it's not enough to find a solution that solves the problem as given. You have to find the right algorithm *and* efficient coding. Example: you don't need a function call to perform `getMax`. It is trivial to do in-line. Also function `copyArray()` - it's almost certain that the library function `memcpy()` will be faster than your own version.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to look at the hints in the question. `:)` (Reading the hint will change how you approach your solution. But even so, you will have to employ some [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) strategy so that yo don't calculate the same things over and over again.)  Keep the slow code as reference. It will be good only for small arrays, but if you are sure it's correct, you can create test cases for the optimized solution.